# converting a whole table/dataframe in pyarrow a dictionnay_encoded columns

Tags: python, pyarrow

am loading a parquet file from apache arrow (pyarrow), and so far, i necessarily needs to transfer to pandas, doing a conversion as categorical, and send it back as arrow table (to save it later as feather file type)

the code looks like it :

```py
    df = pq.read_table(inputFile)
    # convert to pandas
    df2 = df.to_pandas()
    # get all cols that needs to be transformed and cast
    list_str_obj_cols = df2.columns[df2.dtypes == "object"].tolist()
    for str_obj_col in list_str_obj_cols:
        df2[str_obj_col] = df2[str_obj_col].astype("category")

    print(df2.dtypes)
    #get back from pandas to arrow
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df2)
    # write the file in fs
    ft.write_feather(table, outputFile, compression='lz4')
```

is there anyway to make this directly with pyarrow ? would it be faster ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pyarrow "categorical" is referred to as "dictionary encoded".  So I think your question is if it is possible to dictionary encode columns from an existing table.  You can use the [`pyarrow.compute.dictionary_encode`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.compute.dictionary_encode.html) function to do this.  Putting it all together:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.compute as pc

def dict_encode_all_str_columns(table):
    new_arrays = []
    for index, field in enumerate(table.schema):
        if field.type == pa.string():
            new_arr = pc.dictionary_encode(table.column(index))
            new_arrays.append(new_arr)
        else:
            new_arrays.append(table.column(index))
    return pa.Table.from_arrays(new_arrays, names=table.column_names)

table = pa.Table.from_pydict({'int': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'str': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y']})
print(table)
print(dict_encode_all_str_columns(table))
```